# Finding a lower bound for an exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I have a problem finding a lower bound of the following function. I am sure that I am missing a basic fact, but I could not figure it out.

Assume that there are $t>s$($t, s\neq 0$) and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$f(n, m):=\frac{e^{s(n+m)}}{e^{t(n+m+k)}}.$$

Can we find a non zero uniform lower bound for  $f$? That means there is $C>0$ such that for all $m,n$, $f(m,n)\geq C.$

Cam we find the minimum of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your expression as
$$f(n,m) = e^{(s-t)(n+m)}e^{-kt}.$$
Now, $n+m$ can be arbitrarily large, so that since $s-t<0$,
the first factor approaches zero as $n+m \rightarrow \infty$.

If $t>0$, $e^{-kt} \leq 1$, so that the only uniform lower bound is clearly zero.
For $t<0$, we can always choose $n+m$ such that $(t-s)(n+m)-k|t|$ is arbitrarily large.

So, the only uniform bound is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. Assume that $t>0$. Can we get some uniform lower bound which depends on $k$ and $t$? Because I do need    Some $C>0$ not $0$.

Comment: For instance, can we say that $f(n,m)\geq C$ where $C(k, t)=:C>0?$

Comment: @Adam, no I don't think so.  If $k$ and $t$ are fixed positive numbers, and you give me a number, no matter how small, I can find value of $n$ and $m$ that will make $f$ smaller than this number.

Comment: Yeah! $t$ and $k$ are fixed. The reason is if the lower bound is zero, then the one side of an inequality, which this question appeared, becomes zero, which I don't want.

Comment: One more question, does the minimum attain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The infimum of zero is not attained.